# Problem sending signals to child processes

Tags: c, winapi, console, signals, handler

I have a server that sets up a console handler with the `SetConsoleCtrlHandler()` function at startup and creates a number of child processes.
My goal is this:

- the server receives the `CTRL+C` signal
- the server generates the same signal to all active child processes of
  the same `group`
- the child processes manage the signal and correctly complete their
  execution

This is my code:

```
//handler for server.c
BOOL WINAPI CtrlHandler( DWORD fdwCtrlType ) 
{ 

    //CTRL_C_EVENT
    if(fdwCtrlType == CTRL_BREAK_EVENT)
    {
        newConf=1;
        return TRUE;
    }
    else if(fdwCtrlType == CTRL_C_EVENT)
    {
        //send CTRL+C to all process with the same groupId of calling process
        GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(0,0);//
        return FALSE;     
    }
}

// server.c main
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ...
    ...
    if(!SetConsoleCtrlHandler(CtrlHandler, TRUE))
    {
        getLastError("SetConsoleCtrlHandler failed");//function written by me
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ... 
    ...
    //This is how I create child processes (in a for loop)
    STARTUPINFO info;
    GetStartupInfo(&info);
    WSAPROTOCOL_INFO protInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
    if(!CreateProcess("workerProcess.exe",command, NULL, NULL,0,CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not create process.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    ...
    ...
}


//handler for child process(workerProcess.c)
BOOL WINAPI CtrlWorkerHandler( DWORD fdwCtrlType ) 
{ 

    //CTRL_C_EVENT
    if(fdwCtrlType == CTRL_C_EVENT)
    {
        printf("\nCLOSING WORKER\n");
        return FALSE;  
    }
    return TRUE; 
}

//workerProcess.c main
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ...
    ...
    if(!SetConsoleCtrlHandler(CtrlWorkerHandler, TRUE))
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"setConsoleCtrlHandler failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

The server correctly handles the `CTRL + C` signal, the `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` function does not fail so I assume it can send the signal to all processes that have the same groupid as the calling process, but unfortunately the `workerProcess.exe` process does not seem to handle the `CTRL+C` signal received from the parent process

Answer (score 0):

Not sure and not able test right now, but I give it shot: by specifying `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` ([The new process is the root process of a new process group.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/process-creation-flags)) for *each* worker process you basically create a new process group for each worker process.

Then, however, the call to `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(0, 0)`, where the second `0` says [the signal is generated in all processes that share the console of the calling process.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/generateconsolectrlevent) seems to be futile. All the worker processes are not even in the same process group as the calling process.

Probably, you should remove the `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` flag when creating the worker processes, or remember the [`lpProcessInformation.dwProcessId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-process_information) value for each worker process and invoke `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` for each.